# Inserting PHP into placeholder

Tags: php, placeholder

I sometimes insert PHP to build varying placeholders.

This time, I want to create an entire input field ($content_message) that varies depending on certain other things on my page:

```
$content_message = "<input type='password' name='pw' size='30' minlength='8' maxlength='255' placeholder='"
               . "<?php if(empty($pwErr)) {echo "
               . "'New Password'"
               . ";} else {echo $pwErr;}>'"
```

My placeholder always displays

```
<?php if(empty()) {echo
```

and I don't know what else to do. I already tried changing the " to ' and I used a PHP Code Checker, but still it does not work.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: PHP will not execute commands that are strings. If you want your PHP code to run, you need to take it out of the string. I.e. `$content_message="<input type='password' name='pw'".(empty($pwErr)?'New Password':$pwErr);`

Comment: @ctwheels I think he's building a string to insert into a page that will execute later.

Comment: @sebjel Can you give an example of when you just built a placeholder please :-)

Comment: First comment already worked, thanks guys!